# Program 'main.exe' failed to run: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-code

“I’m setting up Visual Studio Code, and when I try to run my main.cpp (main.exe when executed), It is showing the error mentioned above.

From what I read about the issue online. I think it is because of wrong written in the c_cpp_properties.json file. But I can't figure out where to make the changes.

```
#Code:

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Hello World"<<std::endl;
}

#c_cpp_properties.json :

{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceRoot}",
                    "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\8.2.0\\include\\c++"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

## Error Message:

Program 'main.exe' failed to run: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.At line:1 char:1
+ .\main.exe+ ~~~~~~~~~~.
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

Comment: Can you compile (and run) it from `cmd.exe`?

Comment: I am embarrassed but i am gonna say it, you see after i executed the program the "main.exe" file was created and i was trying to execute for hours with no sucess, now when i checked there is an additional file "a.exe", i yries to execute that viola "hello world".

Comment: Can you please guide me to avoid such confusion in the future?

Comment: I am having this error even when i have typed     ``` '.\a.exe'```  in my terminal, which is vscode.  ```Program 'a.exe' failed to run: The specified
executable is not a valid application for this OS      
platform.At line:1 char:1
+ ./a
+ ~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ ./a
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable:     
   (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed ```

Answer (score 4):

You're getting this error because you're building on 64 bit windows machine with 32bit cpp.exe. So you're building for a different target machine.
To fix this, change your tasks.json file to point to g++.exe instead of cpp.exe.

To access your tasks.json file on windows (ctrl+shift+p) and then type "tasks"

change cpp.exe to g++.exe

Answer (score 1):

I, too, faced the same error but rectified it with a simple solution

1.) First go and check your extensions whether you have installed the C/C++ by Microsoft.

2.) If not, do that first!

3.) If you have already installed, don't worry, check the version of your Visual Studio Code by clicking **help** in the menu bar and pressing **About**.

**For version 2.0.0:**

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "Build",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "g++",
        "args": [
            "-o",
            "main",
            "-g",
            "main.cpp"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    },
    {
        "label": "Run",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": ".\\main",
        "problemMatcher": []
    }
]
```

}

**For version 1.0.0:**

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "make",
"isShellCommand": true,
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "Makefile",

        // Make this the default build command.
        "isBuildCommand": true,

        // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
        "showOutput": "always",

        // Pass 'all' as the build target
        "args": ["all"],

        // Use the standard less compilation problem matcher.
        "problemMatcher": {
            "owner": "cpp",
            "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceRoot}"],
            "pattern": {
                "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                "file": 1,
                "line": 2,
                "column": 3,
                "severity": 4,
                "message": 5
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

4.) Check your version properly and paste the above-mentioned syntax in your **tasks.json**.

To go to tasks.json Do the following steps:

1. Press Ctrl+Shift+P.
2. You will see your command palette where you must type configure tasks. And select (“Tasks: Configure Task”).
3. You can type the above-mentioned syntax with respect to your Visual Studio Code Version.
   **Don't miss out the ending curly braces mentioned below the syntax**

Comment: This worked like a charm for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For me you just need to configure your task.json file

My tasks.json file is this:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-o",
                "main",
                "-g",
                "main.cpp"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "Run",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": ".\\main",
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Also to run the exe file the command is ".\filename" **without the extension**.

Answer (score -1):

We can execute cpp Programs using

> **g++** name_of_file.cpp
>
> ./a

Or for c prgrams

> **gcc** name_of_file.c
>
> ./a