# Error trying to execute C++ on Windows (compiled via MinGW)

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, executable

So I tried for the first time to compile and run a c++ "app" I did (trying to make an easy exercise for my girlfriend) but when trying to run it on Powershell, I got this error:

```
Program 'Exercice_1.exe' failed to run: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.At
line:1 char:1
+ .\bin\Exercice_1.exe
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\bin\Exercice_1.exe
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

The code is just an attempt at doing my own List (well, it's not yet fully coded, but I feel like it's more related to the system than to the code...)

When I only had a laptop, I coded on Code::Blocks, but there I tried to compile and run via command lines on a desktop computer, and I don't know if I have to install anything to make it work or if it should work.

The makefile content:

```
CC = g++
CFLAG = -Wall -pedantic
STD = -std=c++11
SRC = src/
INC = include/
OBJ = object/
BIN = bin/

$(BIN)Exercice_1.exe: $(SRC)Exercice_1.cpp $(OBJ)Liste.o $(OBJ)Maillon.o
    $(CC) $(STD) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAG)

$(OBJ)Liste.o: $(SRC)Liste.cpp $(INC)Liste.h $(INC)Maillon.h
    $(CC) $(STD) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAG)

$(OBJ)Maillon.o: $(SRC)Maillon.cpp $(INC)Maillon.h
    $(CC) $(STD) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAG)

clean:
    rm -f -R object/*.o
    rm -f -R *~

mrproper: clean
    rm -f $(BIN)*.exe
```

I took it from an old exercise I had to do and rearranged it to work with my current attempt and I'm pretty sure it should work well, so I don't know what doesn't work.

If needed: the Exercice_1.cpp file:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "../include/Maillon.h"
#include "../include/Liste.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Maillon<int>* maillon = new Maillon<int>(7);
    std::cout << maillon->get_info() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

Result of `g++ --version`

```
g++.exe (MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-5) 8.2.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

System info:

```
System Type:               x64-based PC
```

RE-EDIT:

Error found, it was in the makefile...
As I copied it from an old project, I did not copy it correctly, here is the more correct version:

```
CC = g++
CFLAG = -Wall -pedantic
STD = -std=c++11
SRC = ./src/
INC = ./include/
OBJ = ./object/
BIN = ./bin/

$(BIN)Exercice_1.exe: $(OBJ)Exercice_1.o $(OBJ)Liste.o $(OBJ)Maillon.o
    $(CC) $(STD) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAG)

$(OBJ)Exercice_1.o: $(SRC)Exercice_1.cpp $(INC)Liste.h $(INC)Maillon.h
    $(CC) $(STD) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAG)

$(OBJ)Liste.o: $(SRC)Liste.cpp $(INC)Liste.h $(INC)Maillon.h
    $(CC) $(STD) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAG)

$(OBJ)Maillon.o: $(SRC)Maillon.cpp $(INC)Maillon.h
    $(CC) $(STD) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAG)
```

It now doesn't compile but because I've obviously made errors in the code and am trying to correct them.

Thanks a lot to everyone, and mostly to mklement0 for trying to help, it was very pleasant to see how nice is this community!

RE-RE-EDIT:

It now works fine :D

Comment: Is this an exe you compiled on a Linux machine you're trying to run on a windows machine?

Comment: `g++` is usually a linux compiler, are you using something like MinGW for compiling on Windows?

Comment: @NathanOliver It's compiled on a Windows machine

Comment: @Romen I'm using MinGW, yes

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57436926/program-main-exe-failed-to-run-the-specified-executable-is-not-a-valid-applic) which seems related but am not using VSCode so I don't know if it is related or not... I used to have it but uninstalled it a few days ago, if it may help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**: This answer provides *background information*: it may or may not solve your problem.

The problem is that **Windows doesn't know how to invoke your executable, because it doesn't use the required binary file format**.

You say that you've used [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) to compile your executable, which *is* designed to create native Windows applications.

Since an accidentally *empty* file is *not* your problem (see below), you need to investigate what type of executable file format your MinGW compilation process actually uses for file `.\bin\Exercice_1.exe`.

---

A *possible* reason for your symptom is:

If `.\bin\Exercice_1.exe` happens to be an *empty* (`0` bytes) file rather than the expected executable, the result would be the error message you saw:

```
# Create an empty *.exe file and try to invoke it.
PS> $null | Set-Content notreal.exe; ./notreal

Program 'notreal.exe' failed to run: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
...
```

You then need to investigate how the empty `.\bin\Exercice_1.exe` file was accidentally created, and why your compilation didn't place a valid executable there.

Comment: The .\bin\Exercice_1.exe file is a 3KB file with like 139 lines of non-understandable values, so it is apparently not empty...
I also changed the name of the question according to your comment, hoping it is now more related to my problem.